# OpenGrok project picklist doesn't show as I want

Tags: opengrok

The opengrok version: opengrok-1.1-rc3

My project picklist displays like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQy1X.png)

But, I want it to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqBNL.png)

Thanks！！！

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the project picklist shows in the OpenGrok 1.x version. The way you want is used in the 0.x versions of OpenGrok. There's nothing you can do to have the old project picklist in the 1.x version. BTW IMHO the new version of the project picklist is better.